# VBA Macro overflow

Tags: vba, excel

Having a problem with this code. 
my coding is the following:

```
    fitvalchild1 = 0
    fitvalchild2 = 0

    For i = 1 To 30                            
        counter = 30

        Do While counter > 0
            fitvalchild1 = fitvalchild1 + child1(counter) * 2 ^ (i - 1)
            fitvalchild2 = fitvalchild2 + child2(counter) * 2 ^ (i - 1)
            counter = counter - 1
        Loop
    Next i
```

all the variables are declared as long...

Still i get the Error : overflow and the line highlighted is:

```
fitvalchild1 = fitvalchild1 + child1(counter) * 2 ^ (i - 1)
```

Comment: So, what's in the child1() arrays?

Comment: If child1(counter) = 4 you will get an overflow when i=30.

Comment: both child arrays contains a binary code, where each array contains a bit. for example child1(1) can be equal to 1 or zero and so forth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Long` datatype has a maximum size of 2,147,483,647.
2 ^ (30-1) = 536,870,912
so, depending on the value of `child1(counter)` and `fitvalchild1`, you'll easily exceed the maximum.

You're adding the value to itself with each loop, so after 4-5 loops, you'll likely get the error.

If you don't mind switching away from an integer type, you might try using `Currency` datatype.  It has a maximum size of 922,337,203,685,477.5807

Comment: @JeffO -- Good point.  `Decimal` gives you an even larger range and may even be better precision...maybe depends on the need.  You could also try `Variant` and let the system decide how to store it.

Answer (score 1):

The range for the long data type is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The values in child1 and child2 don't need to very big to overflow since 2^29 is very close to the limit.